# What's the proper name to call a bunch of coins?

Tags: word-request, collective-nouns

Is it "amount", "bunch", "pack", "wallet" or something else?

The thing here is that I'm a programmer and I'd like to create a new variable to store the number of coins in it, but I'm not sure how to name it in English.

Comment: A good question.  I'm not sure we have a common word for "a ____ of coins".  You could say a **pile**, a **stack**, a **handful**, etc.  But most of those have to do with the shape or the kind of container, not with the coins themselves.

Comment: In a program you work with the quantity or the number of the coins, I don't know why you want a word to describe a bunch of coins. you can use "NumberOfCoins" or "NumOfCoins" or even "Coins"

Comment: @Ahmad, my class name is `Coin` so I guess that I would have to have another name for that variable. I might continue to use `quantity`. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for help naming entities within a programming context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Not all programming terms are off-topic here; this is basically asking about the plain English, not how to name an EnhancedCoinWalletTransactionManagerFactory.

Comment: He's asking about the proper word to describe a collection of coins. Sure, the context is specifically a computer program. So what? Any question presumably has SOME context. If he said that he was a bank teller and he was looking for the word to describe a bunch of coins, would you say out of scope because it's about banking and not English?

Comment: If all of the coins are of the same denomination, the correct technical term is a **roll**. http://coins.about.com/od/uscoins/f/roll_of_coins_f.htm. I have seen the  term **a jangle of coins** used for a random collection of coins, but I can't find a reference to it: definitely a neologism, but i think a nice one.

Comment: I think "roll" is only the correct term if the coins are, in fact, in a roll. If I had twenty loose nickels in my pocket, I don't think anyone would call that "a roll of nickels".

Comment: I think that this question has some potential, but we definitely need more input from the OP about what he really wants before we consider re-opening it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context you describe, you don't really want a word for "a bunch of coins", you want a word that means "quantity". "Number", "quantity", "amount", "count", any such word would do. If you have other variables describing the number of other things -- paper bills, credit cards, whatever, I'd use the same word for consistency.

Depending just what you're trying to say, "amount" would likely imply the value of the coins while "count" or "number" would be the number of individual coins. Like if I had 10 nickels, I'd say "count" is 10 but "amount" is probably 50 cents.

I think you do not at all want a word specific to "a bunch of coins". Think of comparable words. If you ran a farm and you had a variable where you stored the number of cows on your farm, a good name would be "number" or "count", just like here. You wouldn't want to call it "herd", because a group of cows is called a herd. set cows.count=47 makes sense and anyone reading the code could easily guess what it meant. set cows.herd=47 ... what does that mean? You have multiple herds and this is number 47? You have 47 herds? It wouldn't help at all.

Comment: Makes perfectly sense. I'll change the correct answer to this one because has a broader approach instead only to programming!

Answer (score 3):

According to the comments, you have a class named `Coin`. In many classes, the **Count** property is used for such purposes. Then you don't need to repeat `Coin` which is the name of class and `Count` is enough. **Quantity** is another option.

Answer (score 2):

There are many words that could be used to describe a group of coins, depending on how they are arranged or what they are contained within.  However, for naming a variable I would ignore them all and simply name the variable NumberOfCoins.

Comment: my class name is `Coin` so I guess that I would have to have another name for that variable. Should I just use `quantity`?

Comment: Based on the extra information I agree with the accepted answer - Quantity, Count or Number would be good names.